# Optimizing difficult mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing forum. Table struct is:

```
forum_threads:
  id: int unsigned, primary key
  forum_id: int unsigned
  flags: int unsigned. (1 - closed, 2 - important, etc.)
  views: int unsigned

forum_thread_views_count: (is a MEMORY table, needed to reduce IO operations)
  thread_id: int unsigned, primary key
  views: int unsigned

forum_posts:
  id: int unsigned, primary key
  thread_id: int unsigned
  author_id: int unsigned
  flags: int unsigned
  creation_date: int unsigned (unix timestamp)
```

I need to select: `forum_thread.id`, `forum_thread.flags`, `forum_thread.views`, `forum_thread_views_count.views`, `COUNT(forum_posts)`, `MIN(forum_posts.id)`, `MAX(forum_posts.id)` by `forum_thread.forum_id` ordered by `forum_posts.creation_date DESC`. First must be selected important themes (flags & 2).

Now i has query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.flags, t.views, tv.views, COUNT(p.id), MIN(p.id), MAX(p.id)
FROM forum_threads t
LEFT JOIN forum_thread_views_count tv ON tv.thread_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN forum_posts p ON p.thread_id = t.id
WHERE t.forum_id = 1
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.flags & 2 DESC, p.creation_date DESC;
```

this is works, but, i think, it can be made better.

Comment: indexes? those should help

Comment: You could put post count, first post, and last post into the forum_threads table if you want to avoid that join.

Comment: @xd6_ Indexes already exists. Explain result: http://clip2net.com/s/7fAtDI

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make it better.  First, unless there is a valid reason for using outer joins, use inner joins.  Next, change your group by from

```
GROUP BY t.id
```

to

```
GROUP BY t.id, t.flags, t.views, tv,views
```

While MySQL allows you to mismatch your select and group by clauses, it might cause you to get incorrect results.

Comment: LEFT JOIN forum_thread_views_count, bsecause it can return null (fore example, this thread has no visitor last *save_views_interval* minutes). Changed forum_posts join to INNER JOIN. Explain, please, how it can return incorrect results, when t.id is unique (primary key)?